# JQuery / JavaScript threading issue - Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

OK, this might be a stupid question, so forgive me in advance. I have a webpage (content mostly unimportant) in which I need to make about 100 ajax calls synchronously (only because I don't know how to do async/multithreading in JavaScript, and because I don't want to hammer the server I'm calling).

Because this will take a while, I'm trying to use a jQuery dialog (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal) to show a modal dialog so that the user knows it will take a while. My function looks like this:

```
$("#modalDiv").dialog({ modal: true, title: "Calling server" });
for (var i = 0; i < callsToMake.length; i++) {
    // make a call
}
```

The problem is the modal dialog shows up, but not until my calls are complete, which is pointless. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be to force your long-running calls to execute after the dialog opens by using setTimeout ...

```
$("#modalDiv").dialog({ modal: true, title: "Calling server" });
setTimeout(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < callsToMake.length; i++) {
    // make a call
  }
  $("#modalDiv").dialog("close"); //close the dialog
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a sample of a possible solution simulating the ajax calls:

http://jsfiddle.net/px7fc/20/

Basically you have to create a similar mechanism to make sure your calls have made through the server and came back with your info.. then you update your ui with the data you received and check your collection to see whether or not all calls have been made, and if they do, you just close the modal..

this sample is not great, i just made it so it *works*.. but it's merely to show the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Making requests synchronously does not reduce load on your server, it just makes the user's browser unresponsive.  What you should be thinking is how can I reduce my server calls to 1.  If you can't do that, you need to track when the AJAX calls are completed.

To track when all calls are complete, you can go about it one of two ways.  There's not enough code to build you code samples, so here is a short description of what to do.

**Easiest/Hack**
Use the [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) event.

The idea here is you loop and issue all of your ajax calls.  Assuming only these calls are going on at the time.  At the end of running `$.ajax` 100 times, register `ajaxStop` event.  When all of the ajax events are completed, this callback will be issued.  You can then close the dialog.

**Proper way**
Learn about the [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object.  I won't pretend that this is easy.

You create a deferred object that is aware of all of the ajax calls.  When they are all complete, you can then fire off your `dialog.close()`.  I can provide a short example if this method intrigues you.  Otherwise, use the hack above which will work in simple cases.

Comment: When I say that I need to run them synchronously, I mean 1 at a time. I don't want a few hundred requests to hit my server at once. Thanks though!

Comment: I would like to see an example of the deffered object, thanks!

Comment: You should never make synchronous requests, if you want them to go one at a time. You would make the first ajax return start the next one.  It would be far more efficient to issue all at the same time though, then organize the result.

Comment: So depending on how you want to do it, the process I'm describing here can be implemented with this gist: https://gist.github.com/1219564

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue:

And as general solution this would be the algorithm:

```
showModal();
setTimeout(function() {
  doLongJob();
  removeModal();
}, 200);
```